# Load different view controllers inside UIView (Like iFrame for Xcode)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am in the process of making my first iPhone app with storyboard in Xcode and am stuck. My main screen has a view controller called MemberViewController, which is the home screen. This screen has a UIView that is smaller than the view controller called mainContent.

So basically, I want to be able to load different view controllers (all the same size as the UIView) inside the UIView.

MemberViewController (home page)
 -mainContent (UIView)

GetStartedViewController (separate view controller that I want to show inside the UIView)
ProfileViewController (separate view controller that I want to show inside the UIView)

For example, I want the GetStartedViewController to have a button that I can press to switch to the ProfileViewController. The view controllers need to be able to replace each other inside the mainContent UIView.

Thank you so much in advance for your help. If there's an easier way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Watch the “Implementing UIViewController Containment” video from [WWDC 2011](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/).

Comment: You might also see if you can just use a `UITabBarController`.

Comment: I already have a tab controller, but it's on the side of the screen, so it's not a UITabBarController. The reason I'm trying to have view controllers load inside a UIView is so that I can have this bar on every page of the app without having to create it and copy/paste repeatedly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this technique a lot actually. My typical setup of a root `UIViewController` (you call it `memberController`) has a view with a `UITabBar` at the bottom, and then another `UIView` (you call it `mainContent`) which contains the rest of the space above that bar.

`memberController` stays on the screen all the time. Inside of `mainContent`, add a `UINavigationController` and initialize it with your first content-carrying `GetStartedViewController`. When you want to switch tabs on your tab bar, send the appropriate message to this `UINavigationController` and the views will change inside.

HINT: say your `UINavigationController` is called `navController` - you can get rid of the navigation bar (blue one at the top) by sending the message `[navController setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE];`

EDIT: The code you requested looks like this. This adds a nav controller to a window's view in the `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. Instead of window, just do this same thing on your view controller in the `viewDidLoad`.

`window` and `navController` are both properties

```
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[YourViewController new]];
[self.navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
[self.window addSubview:self.navController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! I'd vote you up if I could, I'm only a level 1 :(

Comment: Hey nick, could you give me some sample code about how to add a UINavigationController? I'm not sure where to create it in my code. Do I make it in the init method of the memberController class?